# Not getting text box values in Managed Bean

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

I am not able to get username and password values that I am entering on the xhtml page in my ManagedBean.

This is why i am getting NullPointerException in goodBye method when I am checking username and password

**Login.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:lang="en">
<f:view>
    <head>
<title>Test Client Login</title>
    </head>
    <h:form id="loginForm">
        <table align="center" border="1" style="padding-top: 100px">
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="username2">
                        <h:outputText id="usernameLabel" value="Enter Username:" />
                    </h:outputLabel>
                </td>
                <td><h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}"
                        required="true">
                        <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="500" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputLabel for="password2">
                    <h:outputText id="passwordLabel" value="Enter Password:" />
                </h:outputLabel></td>
                <td><h:inputText id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}"
                    required="true">
                    <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="500" />
                </h:inputText></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h:commandButton id="goodbyeCommand" type="submit" value="submit"
                    action="#{loginBean.goodbye}" immediate="true" />
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
</f:view>


</html>
```

**LoginBean.java**

```
package com.example.ws.ui;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Managed Bean for Login
 * 
 */
public class LoginBean { 

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginBean.class); 


    //EbzWS userManager;

    private String username;
    private String password;  
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String goodbye() {
    /*  try {

            userManager.getEbzById("asdad", "asdad");
            logger.info("method called");
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }*/
        String dest = "failure";
        if(username.equals("sunny") && password.equals("sunny")){
            dest = "success";
        }
        return dest;
    }
    /*public EbzWS getUserManager() {
        return userManager;
    }
    public void setUserManager(EbzWS userManager) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }*/

}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
    <managed-bean>
        <description>Login Bean</description>
        <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.example.ws.ui.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <description>EBZ Bean</description>
        <managed-bean-name>getEbzByIdBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.example.ws.ui.GetEbzByIdBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <description>WsListing Bean</description>
        <managed-bean-name>wsListingBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.example.ws.ui.WsListingBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <description>Navigation from the hello page.</description>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/wsListing.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/failure.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <description>Navigation from the hello page.</description>
        <from-view-id>/wsListing.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>ebzService</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/ebzinput.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>filterEbz</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/filterebzinput.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>


    <navigation-rule>
        <description>Navigation from the hello page.</description>
        <from-view-id>/ebzinput.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/ebzoutput.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <application>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Can tell us the JSF version you are using..??? also can u show how you defined the Managed Bean..??

Comment: @Mango Please find the attached faces-config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `immediate="true"` on your command button causes JSF to skip all lifecycle phases until INVOKE APPLICATION. So your values are not set. Remove this attribute and it should work as expected.

Comment: I am using faces-config.xml, so i have specified the ManagedBean overthere. Then also it is not working

Comment: Can you explain me in detail or provide me some link so that I can read about it.

Comment: I recommend reading this [great post](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your managed bean should be in the following way

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.ws.ui.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>       
</managed-bean>
```

also in your xhtml page:

```
<td><h:outputLabel for="username">     
 <h:outputText id="usernameLabel" value="Enter Username:" />                           </h:outputLabel>                       </td>
```

as id for `><h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" required="true">` is "username"

Comment: also try removing type="submit" and immediate= "true" from your <h:commandButton>

Answer (score -1):

The problem found in validateLongRange validator. You entered a string and you must use validateLength. validateLongRange is used for double values

hope this answer is write